# Oracle case in where clause with expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, where-clause

I have the following query in oracle 10g:

`select  IN_OUT_DATE, STORE_NO, ART_NO, SUPPL_NO, SUPPL_TYPE, QTY
     from oltp_transactions_hist 
     where art_no = :art_no and store_no = :store_no and in_out_type<50 and in_out_date between :X and :Y`

and I want to add in **where** clause the following **expression** in case that variable :all is zero:

`case
WHEN :all = 0 OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_BEF<>OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_AFT
END CASE;`

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you want something like `(:all = 0 AND OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_BEF<>OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_AFT) OR :all <> 0`

Comment: can you give me the complete where clause because I get syntax errors?

Comment: `where art_no = :art_no and store_no = :store_no and in_out_type<50 and in_out_date between :X and :Y AND ((:all = 0 AND OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_BEF<>OLD_NN_BUY_PRICE_AFT) OR :all <> 0)`

Comment: There was also a conflict with the variable :all that seems to be keyword, I changed it to :all_view and now is working fine

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression returns a value of any datatype except for `boolean` that could be compared to another value. The `where` clause requires a condition or sets of conditions that are true or false for a given set of data.

Moreover, `case` and `where` are two different things. You can definitely use `case` constructs in a `where` clause but you must know their purpose. A `case` construct compares a set of conditions and returns a value whereas the `where` clause is used for filtering rows as per the requirement.

For example, to clarify further, consider the following code:

```
select 1 as coll
  from dual
 where case :x
           when 1 then 2
           else 0
       end = 2;
```

You cannot remove the ending phrase `= 2` because you need to **compare** the value returned by the `case` construct with something. You cannot simply throw in an open-ended `case` construct in a `where` clause, without comparing its value with anything. Moreover, if you enter x=1, you'll get a row. If you don't, you won't.